# GHCi sees Happstack.Server, but GHC doesn't. What's going on?

Tags: haskell, cabal, happstack

I want to install, and use Happstack, and what should of taken 10 minutes, has been bugging me all day. First off, I had to wrestle with Cabal, and eventually gutted it out, and installed a fresh copy, and updated it:

```
# I use Fedora 16... 
yum remove cabal-install
...
yum install cabal-install
...
cabal update
...
# I was told that a new version was available.
cabal install cabal-install
...
cabal install happstack-server
```

None of these commands failed (or at least they didn't give the impression that they did.)

With it now *installed*, I decided to try and build the first, simple example found in the [Crashcourse guide](http://www.happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/HelloWorld.html#first_app).

I have it written as:

```
-- server.hs
module Main where

import Happstack.Server (nullConf, simpleHTTp, toResponse, ok)

main :: IO()
main = simpleHTTP nullConf $ ok "Hello World!"
```

When I try to compile it with GHC using the commandline of:

```
ghc --make -threaded server.hs -o server
```

I get the following error:

```
server.hs:3:8:
    Could not find module `Happstack.Server':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

and using the suggested `-v` option gives:

```
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.0.4, for Haskell 98, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.0.4
Using binary package database: /usr/lib/ghc-7.0.4/package.conf.d/package.cache
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.2.0.0-6bf7b03ebc9c668817e4379b6796c0c2
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-0.2.0.3-4c5ab8b517f0b5d4ecf2153d5dfb7f41
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.3.1.0-4582a5bc64f22f03f6d960b4f15c981f
wired-in package rts mapped to builtin_rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.5.0.0-958de6d18727479331372229849ac6b8
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
Hsc static flags: -static
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: 
*** Deleting temp dirs:
Deleting: 
ghc: no input files
```

Honestly, I'm having a hard time interpreting that. Anyways, I decided it was time to Google (again!) That lead me to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740746/haskell-web-framework) (*Which is messy and not very useful by the way...*), and it suggested trying to load the module in GHCi.

I gave it a shot, and to my surprise, this works:

```
> :m Happstack.Server
> simpleHTTP nullConf $ ok "Hello World!"
> 
> ...MODULE LOADING INFORMATION HERE...
```

as well as this:

```
> :l server
> main
```

Both run and behave as they should.

So in short, this is weird, Cabal is a hassle, and I don't really have much experience with the basic Haskell toolset (yet.)

Anyone got any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Try compiling without --make or --threaded (and use -O2 while you are at it).  Also check that ghci is invoking the same version of ghc since ghc keeps a different package cache per ghc version.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I tried compiling it like you said, but it hasn't made any difference. Also, how can I check which version of GHC is being invoked by GHCi?

Comment: @Miguel Run `ghc --version` and `ghci --version`.

Comment: You might also post the output from `ghc-pkg --list`.

Comment: It is still very likely that your .cabal directory is wedged somehow. I find the most informative way to figure out what is going on is to run ghci (with out any arguments/filenames/etc) and then enter `:set -v` at the prompt. My expectation is that it will say it is hiding `happstack-server` because it depends on some package that is broken. There might be a long chain of broken things until you get down to the root broken package.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best to write your own `.cabal` file and use Cabal to build your project. Try `cabal init` to get started quickly, and make sure to add `happstack-server` to the `build-depends` of your executable or library.

If you really want to use `ghc --make`, perhaps try passing something like `-package happstack-server` to it.